# Possibility to connect to AWS DocumentDB from outside (not from VPC or ssh tunneling)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, connection, amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

is there a possibility to connect to AWS DocDB outside the VPC without ssh tunneling? From local machine, for example.
I found only documentation that using ssh tunneling from EC2 or from Cloud9.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you want to connect from your machine? There are many ways to connect to DocumentDB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/documentdb-development.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. None of the ways is right for me from your documentation.
I want to connect to documentDB without tunneling traffic through EC2.
I found one solution, but i think it can be not stable. I set up NLB and route traffic to private ip of DocDB instance. I think this IP can changes. Still try to find better solution.

Comment: Ok, but you still did not explain what you're trying to connect. Is it a local program of yours? What DB drivers to you use, if any? This information is necessary to be able to support you.

Comment: Okay I understand. I need to able connect to DocumentDB from my local computer with mongo shell.
There is this comment with command on my DocumentDB cluster page in AWS console:
"Connect to this cluster with the mongo shell"
"mongo --host docdb-devххххххххххххххххх:27017 --username dbadmin --password <insertYourPassword>"

Comment: In that case I'm sorry but there is no way to connect without using an SSH tunnel (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html)

Comment: I think exist way how to workaround. Because in one case i connected to DB, when i set up NLB and point it to DocDB private ip (I got it by run command "host <DB endpoint adress>").
But if i redeploy DB ip will change.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. AWS DocDB documentation says clearly that it is VPC bound application. So the only way to connect from outside is SSH.